# How do I disable the context menu of FlowDocumentScrollViewer, FlowDocumentPageViewer, or FlowDocumentReader?

Tags: wpf, xaml

When displaying `FlowDocument` in WPF, how do I disable the right-click context menu of the `FlowDocumentScrollViewer`, `FlowDocumentPageViewer`, or  `FlowDocumentReader`?

I'd like a pure-XAML solution that can be used in a style, not one that requires a code-behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### FlowDocumentScrollViewer and FlowDocumentPageViewer:

You can use `ContextMenuService.IsEnabled` property.

```
<FlowDocumentPageViewer ContextMenuService.IsEnabled="False" />
```

Or set context menu to null using `{x:Null}` markup extension.

```
<FlowDocumentPageViewer ContextMenu="{x:Null}" />
```

I personally prefer first one because is more readable.

---

### FlowDocumentReader:

Above methods doesn't work for `FlowDocumentReader`, try using this:

```
<FlowDocumentReader>
   <FlowDocument>
       <FlowDocument.ContextMenu>
           <ContextMenu Visibility="Collapsed" />
       </FlowDocument.ContextMenu>
   </FlowDocument>
</FlowDocumentReader>
```